# Advice on platforms/frameworks/languages/etc for a new project

Tags: database, version-control, programming-languages, frameworks

I know this is not a programming question per se, but I wanted to get as much input from the SO community on a new project I hope to get started.  The project is from being started from scratch and thus every decision for programming languages, databases, frameworks, platforms and what not are up in the air.  I'm hoping to get your opinion on the matter, what you feel are the strengths and weaknesses of each option.

***Database:***
Currently I have the option of using MSSQL or MySQL.  While I am leaning towards using MySQL because it is free and most probably has all the features I need.  However, there is the possibility of having a lot of hierarchical data and the new hierarchical data type in MSSQL is quite appealing.  Does it really simplify matters that much?  Also MSSQL supports many more advanced SQL functions that may or may not be useful in the long run.  While for development I can get access to Server 2008, multiple licenses as the development team grows and for production, are the costs justified?

***Programming Languages:***
The project will have a web based front end UI and a server based component that will do some heavy lifting.

For the web based UI, I was thinking of maybe doing Apache/IIS with PHP or IIS with ASP.Net in C#.  I'd like to use a good framework to properly utilize good design patterns that should structure the code and development of the app.  As well as make modifications in the long run easy to implement.  I also want the GUI to look good and don't like the idea of buying .Net controls from component vendors.  Instead I prefer the idea of using good CSS, and open sources like YUI and javascript to make the UI sleek.

For the server based component, I was thinking of using C#.  I have no real development experience in C++ and I'd like good libraries and sufficient speed is good enough.  However, while the web based UI and server based component is loosely coupled, there may be instances where the UI needs to communicate (call methods and what not) with the server based component and I want to pick languages/frameworks that will play nice with each other.

All suggestions on frameworks to incorporate are welcome.

***Version Control:***
I have had good experiences with SVN and a pretty bad experiences with TFS.  I've never worked with GIT.  Which do you think is better in terms of features as well as general developer familiarity.  I want to pick something that other developers will know and not have trouble with.

I apologize if the questions are bit redundant or I'm not providing enough information or using bad terminology.  I plan to edit and improve the question as I get feedback.  Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Who: This would most probably be a startup formed of college students or junior developers.  I want the project to utilize technologies that most people are familiar with or are easy to pick up.

What: I'd need hours and days to explain the solution.  But in the end when you break it down, its a web based UI (think standard web app to just manage database data) that would be used to knowledgeable clients.  The server based component would be very separate except for the fact that it should be able to communicate with the web app.

I can provide more information as required but I would appreciate an opportunity for users to answer and provide their ideas before you hastily close the question.

Comment: Wow, man... isn't this THE question almost any project begin with? It HIGHLY depends on the project's nature...

Comment: Well yeah.  I guess the question should have been, if you could have started a project all over again, what technologies would you have used and why?

Comment: It would depend on WHAT is being built and WHO is building it and tons of other constraints, none of which you describe in the question.  Voted to close.

Comment: Agree with @Brain - I left a smartass answer but @Brian's comment is a more straightforward and kind way of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it depends a lot on specific requirements, but then again, even with those I probably wouldn't be able to tell for sure!

I've been working on a from-scratch project myself for a couple of months, and have generally found:

- Choosing Microsoft for all the layers just goes down much easier (my subjective opinion). For example I would use C# for the UI, the back end, and use MSSQL for the database. Nothing at all wrong with non-Microsoft vendors, I'm no Microsoft fan-boy, I just struggle to get productive with unfamiliar tools. Depends where your experience lies though.
- **Database:** In particular I've found that .NET and MSSQL go easily together. When I started the project I was using a PostgreSQL (because it's free, fully featured and has open-source warm fuzzies). However I abandoned it in favour of MSSQL simply because it was taking me too long to get database work done in an unfamiliar language with unfamiliar tools. Also, I'm not sure MSSQL is so expensive anymore, for example for a web application, MSSQL 2008 Web Edition is pretty damn cheap per-processor I think (only on SPLA licensing though). If you're concerned about database features in a free implementation though, personally I think PostgreSQL has a very full feature set, nicely standardised, and rapidly growing.
- **UI**: I'm pretty inexperienced, but ASP.NET MVC looks far less painful to me than ASP.NET Web Forms. I like PHP too, but again I'd match the UI language with the back-end language, so would recommend .NET.
- On **frameworks**, I'm immersed in DALs at the moment. I like Subsonic for lightweight data, NHibernate for heavy-weight.

I still have a long way to go with my project so perhaps I can only see the short-term benefits and drawbacks at the moment. But in general I would say: use the technologies that you're most comfortable using, as you'll be way more productive and the end result will probably be about the same anyway. If you want to learn new technologies though, and who doesn't? - go ahead, just expect it to take a lot longer.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty good advice.  While I'm not fanboy myself, I'm quite familiar with MS technologies and know I'd be more productive.  But I also know its bottlenecks and see so much better stuff out there, that they are quite appealing to take on and utilize.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't want to answer 'cause it's so open ended. But a few points:

### Money

First, check out [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/). That should take care of any money aspect for 3 years. For a service company, that means not only free VS Team Suite and Office and so on, but free Windows, SQL, etc. If your startup can't afford to spend a bit on MS tech in 3 years, it's *probably* a bad business. So that takes out licensing.

- On a similar note, Sun has [Startup Essentials](http://www.sun.com/emrkt/startupessentials/). Could be interesting on the hardware side of things, but I haven't actually competitively priced them versus Dell/HP.

### Software

It doesn't sound like you have hard enough requirements to say "oh, this slightly-less-popular software X is perfect for my domain Y and is gonna give me a very big boost". In fact, your project might not be like that at all. Maybe it, technically, is going to be a relatively plain application just pushing data around or whatever. You didn't specify.

For a small startup, personal productivity is probably going to trump any other argument. If your people are excellent in X, then that's one of your top arguments right there.

If you really don't have any particular system you're most comfortable with, be conservative. Stick with .NET or Java, as they'll give you the widest range of useful possibilities.

As far as things like OS and Database, I'm biased, but I think Microsoft will give you platforms that are easier to take advantage of than you'll find elsewhere. For instance, setting up load balancing, clustering, centralized authentication, managing servers (updates, events, etc.) is going to be easier to get going on Windows than it would be on another platform, assuming you're not an expert in either. Configuring SQL Server, even the advanced features, is a piece of cake. (Go time someone who knows neither: Setup a DB mirror in MSSQL and MySQL -- which is going to take more work?) Again, this is all predicated on you not having experts in a particular set of technology.

**Don't mix** -- whatever you do, stick with the platform. If you go .NET, MSSQL is going to work better with the data providers (or things like Linq-to-SQL). If you decide to do PHP, then use MySQL as everyone else uses it and you'll encounter less resistance. If you're not inventing stuff on the technical side, don't become an edge case.

Comment: I've been looking at BizSpark and considering it a lot.  Choosing BizSpark means going with MS technologies, so before such decisions get made, I wanted to figure out if it was indeed the right direction.  Thanks for the helpful info.  I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Going into BizSpark means nothing. You aren't obligated to use it at all. You can choose BizSpark, use Office and whatever, then decide to ship on Linux or whatever. You could even run 2 years and toss it all out. All it does is remove the cost from the MS side of things.

Answer (score 1):

You should pick the platform first, then the language that is best for that platform (if there is any choice).

One thing you should consider is the labor pool, and labor pool cost, for specific platforms and languages.  Human Resources can often get cost metrics, if you don't have ideas already.

In my town, for example, .NET platform is much more expensive per Software Engineer than open source, because the .NET developers have a higher rate (40% roughly).  C# is a little higher rate than VB.NET, but also tends to bring more well rounded candidates.

Comment: Thanks, thats definitely an interesting angle from which to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw in something totally different:  How about [weblocks](http://weblocks.viridian-project.de/) as a web framework?  It uses [Hunchentoot](http://www.weitz.de/hunchentoot/) as a server, which can run either standalone or with Apache.  This is all done in Common Lisp.  Weblocks can use [cl-sql](http://clsql.b9.com/) as a backend store, which can connect to many different RDBMs (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, ODBC, SQLite).